# Spread combined comma and colon separated variable into seperate logical columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` with one column `feature_service` that contains one or many pairs of features (*a - d*) with services (*A or B*). features and services are separated using `:` and pairs are separated usign `,`.

The `df` looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(feature_service = c("a:A", "a:A, b:A", "a:A, a:B", "a:B, b:B, c:B", "d:A, d:B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
  feature_service
1             a:A
2        a:A, b:A
3        a:A, a:B
4   a:B, b:B, c:B
5        d:A, d:B
```

Now I want to separate services and features into separate logical columns. The **goal is to have a `data.frame` that looks like**:

```
df_goal <- data.frame(feature_a = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), feature_b = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), feature_c = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
                 , feature_d = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), service_A = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), service_B = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
df_goal
  feature_a feature_b feature_c feature_d service_A service_B
1      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
2      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
3      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE
4      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
5     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
foo <- strsplit(df$feature_service, ",")
# Get all possible features
feature <- unique(unlist(lapply(foo, function(x) trimws(sub(":.*", ":", x)))))
# Get all possible services
service <- unique(unlist(lapply(foo, function(x) trimws(sub(".*:", ":", x)))))

# Generate occurrence table
result <- sapply(c(feature, service), grepl, df$feature_service)
# Name final result
colnames(result) <- c(paste0("feature_", sub(":", "", feature)),
                      paste0("service_", sub(":", "", service)))
```

If you already have all possible features and services then only `sapply` part is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

One option with `mtabulate` after splitting the 'feature_service' column by the delimiters

```
library(qdapTools)
out <- mtabulate(strsplit(df$feature_service, "[:, ]"))[-1] > 0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, create a row names column, split the 'feature_service' with the delimiters in `separate_rows`, get the unique rows (`distinct`), create a logical column of TRUE, and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  separate_rows(feature_service) %>%
  distinct(rn, feature_service) %>%
  mutate(n = TRUE) %>%
  spread(feature_service, n, fill = FALSE)
```

If we need the column names as specified, then after doing the splitting at the `,`, then `separate` into  two columns ('key', 'val'), `gather` from 'wide' to 'long', `unite` the 'key/val' column into a single one, and `spread` as above

```
df %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  separate_rows(feature_service, sep = ", ") %>% 
  separate(feature_service, into = c('feature', 'service')) %>% 
  gather(key, val, feature:service) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  unite(keyval, key, val) %>% 
  mutate(n = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(keyval, n, fill =  FALSE) %>%
  select(-rn)
#  feature_a feature_b feature_c feature_d service_A service_B
#1      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
#2      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
#3      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE
#4      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
#5     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the trio (`baseR`, `tidyverse`, `data.table`), here is my attempt with `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(feature_service, ", |:")]
dcast(melt(dt1, measure = names(dt1)), rowid(variable) ~ value, length)[,variable := NULL][] > 0
```

which gives,

> ```
>          A     B     a     b     c     d    NA
> [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> [2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> ```

**NOTE:** It dummifies `NA` as well, hence the extra column at the end.